# Stuck on White Screen Appears after Facebook login Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK to login to facebook account...
after trying to sign in white screen appears and stuck on it..
this is my code :
`
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

```
Facebook fb;
ImageView pic, button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String APP_ID = "151170088390760"; // getString(R.string.APP_ID);
    fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    updateButtonImage();
}

private void updateButtonImage() {
    if(fb.isSessionValid()) {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
    }else {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(fb.isSessionValid()) {
        try {
            fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
            updateButtonImage();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // login to facebook
        fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new DialogListener(){

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onFacebookError()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                updateButtonImage();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onComplate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

`
I made sure that the Keystore many times 
and I have registered my application to facebook developers site
thank you for helping :)
this is the white screen pic:

[image]

**NOTE:** I'm using the Facebook SDK 3.0.1

**Problem Has been SOLVED:** cuz I tried to login from other facebook account that was not signed as developer

**Thank You**

Comment: I suggest you to move on to the [3.0 SDK version](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0).
The Facebook class is now considered deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was :

I'm trying to login from facebook account not that I signed as a developer

Just signing in from the developer account of the app solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try setting the "Sandbox Mode" to "OFF" in "Basic Info" in Settings of Facebook Apps

Comment: problem has been solved .....
the problem was :
I'm trying to login from facebook account not that I signed as a developer ...
Thank you ALL AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Can not log in with other account? I have encountered the same scenarios. When logging in with another account ,it showed a white dialog with nothing only the delete button on the left top.If a user account ,how to access your app which is not a developer's account.

Comment: you should use your developer account to access the file while you are developing it.... there is no way to access another account while developing process

Comment: I have resolved this problem. I have unchecked the sandbox mode on in the Facebook dashboard,then it can access another account. [http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/16079416/2282026]

Comment: really it solved my problem....thank you alot william
sandbox mode restrict the usage of app to the developer only!